# Minecraft Modding 1.20 : How to create a custom furnace?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I would like to create a custom furnace that needs to be lit by redstone to work, uses fuel and has slots in which to place an item that loses one of its durability each time the furnace is used or each tick while the furnace is lit by redstone.
Okay that's a lot, but even create just a custom furnace which fuels will be great.

I've searched a lot on the internet, but probably not in the right places as everything I've found is outdated and doesn't match what I'm looking for.
I've also taken an in-depth look at the vanilla furnace and blast furnace code, but I have to admit I'm a bit confused.
The next thing I'm probably going to do is download a 1.20 mod that contains custom furnaces and see how they're made but I must admit I'd like to know how the authors figured out the trick.
So if you have any links or tips, I'll be happy to receive them!

Have a nice day !

Comment: Upvoted because there are NO good tutorials on this since 1.15. Perfectly good question